# how many conditions can be written on if in c ++

Tags: c++builder

Hello I did one project and in my one if there were a lot of conditions about 15 I don’t remember exactly and I was wondering how many conditions can be written in if? Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any hard limit on the number of 'if' in the C++ language, this could only be a limitation of your tool chain ( and potentially bad coding practice depending on the number of pages your if() statement takes)

Answer (score 0):

You can go wild with them as there's no limitation as long as you put a valid boolean expression.

But having 15 conditions inside an `if` is a crime. There must be some way you can clean that up. Maybe you can put some of those conditions that have something in common in boolean variables.

Then you do something like this:

```
bool var1 = condition1 && condition2 && ... && condition10
bool var2 = condition11 && condition12 && ... && condition15
if(var1 && var2){
   Do stuff
}
```